# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: r.a.get is not a function in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, github

I am just getting started with `reactjs` and while building a simple React App to fetch `GitHub user details` using an `API`, I got the following error (attached).

Please help me figure out the mistake and let me know why this happens.

Thanks. Cheers !

[Github repo](https://github.com/sourav98/githubcard)

[Check the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8eXl.png)

Comment: Please add the related code or [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in line 8 of `Form.js`

```js
const resp = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.userName}`);
```

And that's normal, because I can read in line 2:

```js
import axios from 'react';
```

You should replace it with

```js
import axios from 'axios';
```